# strip_tags and trim not working properly

Tags: php

I am making a meme generator, Imagick generating the images. My problem is that even if I do some operations on the string I use for the image, the output is incorrect.

By example:

```
$_POST['text_top'] = " test test<br>"; //(starts with a space)
```

Then I do:

```
$text_top = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text_top']));
```

But on the display of $text_top, after I paste the variable on the image, I get:

```
&nbsptest test&lt;br&gt;
```

Why does it happen if I'm calling strip_tags and trim, from what I see, correct and as usual?

All is UTF8 encoded.

Thank!

EDIT: (full code)

```
function wordWrapAnnotation(&$image, &$draw, $text, $maxWidth)
{
$words = explode(" ", $text);
$lines = array();
$i = 0;
$lineHeight = 0;
while($i < count($words) )
{
    $currentLine = $words[$i];
    if($i+1 >= count($words))
    {
        $lines[] = $currentLine;
        break;
    }
    //Check to see if we can add another word to this line
    $metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $currentLine . ' ' . $words[$i+1]);
    while($metrics['textWidth'] <= $maxWidth)
    {
        //If so, do it and keep doing it!
        $currentLine .= ' ' . $words[++$i];
        if($i+1 >= count($words))
            break;
        $metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $currentLine . ' ' . $words[$i+1]);
    }
    //We can't add the next word to this line, so loop to the next line
    $lines[] = $currentLine;
    $i++;
    //Finally, update line height
    if($metrics['textHeight'] > $lineHeight)
        $lineHeight = $metrics['textHeight'];
}
return array($lines, $lineHeight);
}

$text_top = strip_tags(trim($_REQUEST['text_top']));
$text_bottom = strip_tags(trim($_REQUEST['text_bottom']));
$id_base = trim($_REQUEST['id_base']);

/* Création d'un nouvel objet imagick */
$im = new Imagick($_REQUEST['image']);

/* Création d'un nouvel objet imagickdraw */
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

/* Définition de la taille du texte à 52 */
$draw->setFontSize(52);
$draw->setTextAlignment(2);
$draw->setFont("impact.ttf");
$draw->setFillColor('white');
$draw->setStrokeColor("black");
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);

/* Ajout d'un texte */
//$draw->annotation($im->getImageWidth()/2, 50, $text);
list($lines, $lineHeight) = wordWrapAnnotation($im, $draw, stripslashes($text_top), $im->getImageWidth());
$posY= 50;
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++){
$draw->annotation($im->getImageWidth()/2, $posY + $i*$lineHeight, $lines[$i]);
}

$im->drawImage($draw);
```

Comment: Show your full code. There's likely a `htmlspecialchars()` happening somewhere that causes this

Comment: I edited, I also included the function I use to do the word wrapping on the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try this?

```
$text_top = strip_tags(trim(html_entity_decode($_POST['text_top'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), "\xc2\xa0"));
```

It seems like your string is html encoded.

**EDIT**

Added support for UTF-8 encoding. That way, the non-breaking space gets trimmed properly, instead of giving a `?`.

From PHP's `html_entity_decode` documentation:

> Note:
>
> > You might wonder why trim(html_entity_decode(' ')); doesn't
> >     reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the ' '
> >     entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII
> >     code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 encoding.

Comment: Works, but for an unknown reason, html encoding is happening somewhere, not from my code. But still, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this small solution:

```
$str = trim($_POST['text_top']);
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $str);
```

if fist didn't work fine try this:

```
$str = trim($_POST['text_top']);
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/", '', $clean);
$clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
$clean = preg_replace("/[\/_| -]+/", '-', $clean);
```